# Access database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a customer that work with LOGICAISSE, a provider of registry cache that will be connected to MS Access database (yep it's old !)

I need to have access to that database for shopping cart on the web, how to access this kind of database. For now I only have done it with SQL or SQL lite in PHP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't name a specific programming language, here is a [tutorial in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4065-Reading-Access-Databases-with-PHP-and-PECL), for example.

There are also libraries for other languages. Usually you would use ODBC (or a JDBC wrapper) to connect to Access databases.

Answer (score 0):

If using .Net or similar the easy way is to set up an ODBC connection to the access database.

Note that you will need to have read / write access to the share that the access file is located on.  Write is required to create the .lck files that access needs to track whether tables are locked etc.

That said I would seriously argue that you need to pull the data from access into a server like SQL server and have your website hit the SQL server.  Access is NOT built as a multiuser database and treating it like such will lead to a host of issues especially if the website in question has any level of traffic.